# Photo rotated after being decoded into an image

Tags: android, camera, rotation, image-rotation, autorotate

So I have this activity in my app which's supposed to take a picture and then send it to another activity. I forced the orientation to be on portrait mode, and yet, after I take a picture and decode it into a bitmap, it rotates in a seemingly random direction, since I'm unable to fix it by rotating the image by a certain number of degrees.
Any idea why?

```
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length );
};
```

Comment: Ok,  you force the activity orientation to Portrait. Do the users actually hold the device this way? Do they use the same app on tablets where the natural orientation is Landscape?

Comment: The device is supposed to be held on portrait mode, and no, it isn't supposed to be used on tablets. thanks

Comment: You wrote "it rotates in a seemingly random direction". Could this be caused by users holding the device in wrong orientation?

Comment: Also,  do your users always work with the rear camera, or they can choose to switch to front camera,  too ?

Comment: rear camera only, and I haven't tested it on an actual device, since I don't have one, only on the emulator, so it can't be caused by that.

Comment: So you use a webcam with emulator, right?

Comment: Umm the emulated camera they offer, actually.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how the emulated camera works. But maybe it simply produces an image rotated randomly?

Comment: It might, but I highly doubt it. Thank you so much for your time anyway